# ASP.Net Core2: Dynamically disable Security

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm currently trying to make the following work: I use the default security of ASP.net core 2, therefore using Authorization with policies and Authentication with JWT bearer tokens, which checks against Azure Active Directory. Also I would like to use the Authorize-Attributes with the defined Policies. That said, I would like to be able to dynamically overrule this Security, for example for automated integration tests, local development etc.
Unfortunately, this doesn't seem that easy:

I can't just simply not call the .AddAuthentication and .AddAuthorization extensions. If I do this, I get:

```
InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found.
```

I've also tried to override the IAuthorizationService and the AuthenticationHandler. I would just inject my empty implementations via dependency injection. Using this, all sorts of strange effects did happen.

From what I've read, Microsoft did urgently suggest to not override this classes or even create custom Authorize-Attribute. Instead, the Framework in place should be used. Generally, my main goal is to abstract away the dependency to the Azure Active Directory. Is there probably a better way doing this?

Comment: Why not adding a policy requirement/handle which always permits the access and will only be added during integration tests? You can already `env.IsEnvironment("IntegrationTest");` (don't forget to set the environment variable to it.). When you call `context.Succeed(requirement);` in the policy handler it will always succeed, see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: You could make the authentication configurable so you can just skip it or use a mocked authentication handler that will always provide you with a test user. Note that having an integration test that skip an integral part of your application (authentication and authorization) makes it a bad integration test.